How do I connect to a Cassandra cluster from DBeaver community edition?
The DBeaver Cassandra driver is only available in the Pro version. How do I connect to a Cassandra cluster if I'm using the Community Edition?

The Community Edition of DBeaver does not ship with a Cassandra driver out of the box so users will need to source an alternative driver. Fortunately ING Bank has an open-source JDBC wrapper of the Java driver for Apache Cassandra available on GitHub ing-bank/cassandra-jdbc-wrapper.
For a bit of background, cassandra-jdbc-wrapper was originally created by Alexander Dejanovski 9 years ago (2015), then forked by ING Bank in 2020 and they have continued to maintain it since with contributions from the community.
Preparation
Download the latest release of cassandra-jdbc-wrapper JAR from GitHub:

Browse to the Releases section of the repository.
For the latest version, click on the Assets section then click on the corresponding JAR file. For example:


Import the driver
Import the JAR onto DBeaver as follows:

From the file menu, select Database then Driver Manager.
In the dialog box, click on the New button.
In the Settings tab, set the following:


Driver Name: Cassandra ING driver
Class Name: com.ing.data.cassandra.jdbc.CassandraDriver


In the Libraries tab, click on the Add File button.
Select the cassandra-jdbc-version-*-bundle.jar file.
Click on the OK button to create the driver.

At this point, you should be able to see Cassandra ING driver as one of the available drivers in the list.
Connect to Cassandra
In DBeaver, create a new connection to Cassandra as follows:

From the file menu, select Database then New Database Connection.
Select Cassandra ING driver from the list of drivers then click the Next button.
In the Main tab, set the JDBC URL to:

jdbc:cassandra://<contact_point>:9042/<ks_name>?localdatacenter=<dc_name>

where:

contact_point is a list of Cassandra nodes, e.g. 127.0.0.1, or 10.1.2.1--10.1.2.2--10.1.2.3 for providing multiple nodes
ks_name is the default keyspace to use
dc_name is the name of the local DC (default is datacenter1)

WARNING - If you don't provide a keyspace and/or the local DC, the driver will not be able to connect to the cluster.

Click on the Connection details button.
In the Connection name field, enter a database name of your choice then click on the Back button.
Click the Test Connection button to verify that the DB connection is configured correctly.
Click the Finish button to save the new DB connection.

At this point, you should be able to browse the tables and query your Cassandra database if you have configured the connection correctly.
For connecting to clusters with authentication or encryption enabled, see ING's Cassandra JDBC wrapper connection string doc. Cheers!
